# Deleting Recovery partition on a hard drive without OS

Tags: partitioning, windows-explorer, filesystems, multi-boot

I want to create a windows+linux dual boot setup on my PC. I have 3 drives in total, two SSDs(Disks 0 and 1) for each OS and a HDD(Disk 2) that I plan to format and use with NTFS file system for storing data and accessing it on both OS.

Here is an output from diskpart:

```
  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          119 GB      0 B
  Disk 1    Online          465 GB      0 B        *
* Disk 2    Online          931 GB      0 B        *
```

I currently have my windows OS on Disk 1 and some imporant files and documents on Disk 0 that I want to move to Disk 2 and use Disk 0 for my linux OS. However "Windows" doesn't "see" Disk 2 in File Explorer so I decided to try and clean it using diskpart, but I can't. I get the following error when I try to issue the clean command:

Virtual Disk Service error:
Clean is not allowed on the disk containing the current boot,
system, pagefile, crashdump or hibernation volume.

Below you can also find a screenshot from "Disk Management" showing that the drive indeed has multiple partitions:

[image: Disk Management screenshot]

So my questions is:
**How can I delete these partitions and format the disk again, or how can I make the drive discoverable in file explorer?**
I am also open for suggestions if you think there is a better way to set up the dual boot..

Comment: This seems very similar to your question: https://superuser.com/questions/1541727/remove-efi-system-partition-wipe-drive-0/1541745

Comment: Also.. Linux Live boot and gparted will do the trick.

Comment: You cannot delete those partitions within Windows. However, I suspect they are actually used, so you really should not delete them.  I know the EFI partition certainly is currently being used.  Windows does not see the partition, due to the fact, the partition has not been assigned a drive letter.  **I strongly recommend NOT removing any partitions on any of your disks.**